# Wordpress: I want to set p max-width but images to ignore it

Tags: css, wordpress, customization

This is on my portfolio website (Using *Side Full Width* theme and Ebor Portfolio) on Wordpress 4.0.

My text is full width as are my images. But this makes the line-length far too long to be comfortable. I have successfully added `p {max-width: 800px;}` to the custom.css file, but this includes the images (which are placed inline in the portfolio edit page and thus fall under the p tag).

I want the images to remain full width. How can I do this?

### Edit

Thank Tplummer. That didn't work though. I went to the text editor, entered it exactly like you wrote. The IMG writeup however, is not actually inside the same p tag as the text.

### Edit 2

I tried placing images inside the unused h6 tag and left those full width. That seems to have worked! Now the

is floating in the center....which doesn't look bad actually...but my titles are still left....ahhh code is tricky...

Comment: Can you share a link to this wordpress page?

Comment: yeah or add a fiddle of one small content with the css

Comment: Spencer: sure, thanks for the quick response:

Comment: the pages are kind of a mess right now because I'm trial-and-erroring a bunch of different CSS. it's here: billyjacksdesign.com/design-work/the-living-logo. you can also look at any of the other project pages (design-work//happy-hi5-day/ has simple, square images that make it easy to see the edges

Answer (score 0):

If they're nested within the `<p>` tags you're going to have a bad time.

If it's content based, try wrapping the text you want to style inside a span, inside the `<p>` tag.

**CSS**

```
.limit-size { max-width: 800px; }
```

**HTML**

```
<p><span class="limit800">Text text text</span><img src="pic.jpg"></p>
```